# How many NSOperationQueues should an app have?

Tags: ios, multithreading, nsoperationqueue

The question is if an app should have one instance of the queue for all async operations, or several queues can be created?

With one queue it's pretty simple because all tasks are executed based on assigned priority. So for me it's more favourable because there is no need to write extra code.

In the case of multiple queues at least one of them should be main. 
So some sort of queue manager should be implemented that will be able to suspend "sub" queues and allow execution of operations from main queue if needed.

The analogy with only one single connection to database make me think that the one centralised queue should be used for all async operations.

So what would you recommend? What are the best practices?

Comment: In general, I would use NSOperationQueue as either `mainQueue` or `currentQueue`. This is because of a personal preference to use GCD, and utilize custom queues. (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_queue_create)

Comment: how many queues depends on your app.... use the minimal amount needed

Comment: @aug2uag `NSOperationQueue` is based on GCD today

Comment: It's always been based off GCD @Daij-Djan

Comment: @aug2uag no not correct

Comment: Show me your source. As far as I've ever known NSOperationQueue, it's used GCD.

Comment: BTW, managing each and every queue (i.e. an operation that comes for free when using NSOperationQueue, and not GCD by itself) is more important than how many queues are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some searching and brainstorming I came up to the solution.

In my application I'm going to use 2 async queues:
one queue (**NSOperationQueue**) for all background operations (like parsing of downloaded .json files) and another queue (which is already implemented by **NSURLSession** class) for requests (API requests, downloading images, etc).